# bootstrap-select select multiple

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap

Uso esta librería : https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

Posibilidad 1

```
$scope.opciones = [{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":2,"name":"Test2"},{"id":3,"name":"Test3"}] ;
$scope.defecto = [{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":3,"name":"Test3"}] ;

<select ng-model="defecto" class="selectpicker" multiple >
  <option ng-repeat="op.name in opciones" ng-value="op.name">{{op.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer por defecto que marque el 1 y el 3

Posibilidad 2:
Uso de esta librería : https://bentorfs.github.io/angular-bootstrap-multiselect/

```
$scope.result2 = [{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":3,"name":"Test2"}] 

$scope.getValues = function(jdbcId) {
        TestService.getValues(jdbcId).then(
            function(d) {
                $scope.result = [{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":3,"name":"Test2"}] ;
            }
        );
   $scope.result3 = [{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":3,"name":"Test2"}] 
}
```

En mi html

```
{{result}} => me muestra [{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":3,"name":"Test2"}] 

<multiselect ng-model="testing" options="result">
</multiselect> => no funciona
<multiselect ng-model="testing2" options="result2">
</multiselect> => Funciona
<multiselect ng-model="testing3" options="result3">
</multiselect> => Funciona
```

NOTA:

```
<select multiple > , no es viable porque tengo muchos select y me ocuparia mucho la página
```

Comment: En mi ejemplo te muestro una alternativa usando `ng-options`, asignando `$scope.activadas = [1, 3];` sería suficiente, pero te muestro una forma más elegante de tener las dos cosas en una única matriz.

Comment: Solucionado con este post y con la posibilidad 1 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304510/ng-options-in-bootstrap-select-doesnt-work/40304767

Comment: Acabo de llegar y no había leído tu mensaje. Tras un par de pruebas infructuosas con `$watch` para hacer un `refresh` al actualizar la vista encontré [esta directiva](http://myforce.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/) que está desarrollada para ser usada en angular. El problema de tu librería es que modifica el DOM tras haberse generado y es difícil forzar su actualización :( Fíjate como la mayoría de ellos se apoyan en un elemento del DOM por encima del `select`/`option` generado (por ejemplo un `div`) o soluciones similares que permitan regenerarlo sin perder la etiqueta-ng origen.

Comment: Por cierto, enhorabuena :) Deja la solución como respuesta para que pueda darte un voto y que si otra persona se encuentra el mismo problema pueda usar tu solución.

Comment: Hola @sirdaiz , ¿has conseguido hacerlo funcionar? Mira mi respuesta si aún no lo conseguiste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He modificado el código para generarte un ejemplo de la librería que estás usando, espero que te sea de ayuda.

```js
var opciones = [
  { id: 1, sel: true, nombre: "Uno" },
  { id: 2, sel: false, nombre: "Dos" },
  { id: 3, sel: false, nombre: "Tres" },
  { id: 4, sel: true, nombre: "Cuatro" }
];
var stackApp = angular.module('stackApp', ['btorfs.multiselect']);
stackApp
  .controller('Ejemplo',
    ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.test = 'OK';
      $scope.opciones = opciones;
      $scope.activadas = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < opciones.length; i++) {
        if (opciones[i].sel) {
          $scope.activadas.push(opciones[i]);
        }
      }
    }]
);
angular.bootstrap(document, ['stackApp']);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <form ng-controller="Ejemplo">
    <p>{{test}}</p>
    <multiselect ng-model="activadas"
      options="opciones"
      id-prop="id"
      display-prop="nombre"
      multiple>
    </multiselect>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://bentorfs.github.io/angular-bootstrap-multiselect/bower_components/angular-bootstrap-multiselect/dist/angular-bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
```

Segunda tentativa usando directamente [`bootstrap-select`](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/).

```js
var opciones = [
  { id: 1, sel: true, nombre: "Uno" },
  { id: 2, sel: false, nombre: "Dos" },
  { id: 3, sel: true, nombre: "Tres" },
  { id: 4, sel: false, nombre: "Cuatro" }
];
var stackApp = angular.module('stackApp', []);
stackApp
  .controller('Ejemplo',
    ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.test = 'OK';
      $scope.opciones = opciones;
      $scope.selectedOption = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < opciones.length; i++) {
        if (opciones[i].sel) {
          $scope.selectedOption.push(opciones[i]);
        }
      }
    }]
);
angular.bootstrap(document, ['stackApp']);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <form ng-controller="Ejemplo">
    <p>{{test}}</p>
    <select ng-model="opciones"
        class="selectpicker"
        multiple>
      <option
        ng-repeat="op in opciones"
        value="{{op.id}}"
        ng-selected="{{ op.sel == true }}">
        {{op.nombre}}
      </option>
    </select>
    <select class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option name="1">Test 1</option>
      <option name="2">Test 2</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: el problema es que tengo varios select y por eso utilizo esa libreria porque no quiero que la pagina sea muy grande

Comment: debido a que tengo unos 50 select y el cliente no desea verlo así sino como el ejemplo de la librería, edito mi pregunta tb con otra posibilidad que casi me funciona

Comment: he puesto otra alternativa que he probado pero nada :(, sobre todo la segunda posibilidad me gusta más

Comment: bueno me da igual que solucion mientras funcione :)

Comment: solucionado con este post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304510/ng-options-in-bootstrap-select-doesnt-work/40304767

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta con un ejemplo de la librería que estás usando sin necesidad de crear una directiva. Espero que sea de ayuda.

Comment: gracias oscar, ya lo solucione pero viendo tu respuesta es parecida a mi posibilidad 2, echale un ojo por si quieres que lo comentemos. Lo soluciones con la posibilidad 1